# Hide the Event time of p:schedule in primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

I am using the primefaces `<p:schedule>` and i want to hide the event time in some conditions.

The condition i'm using is an attribute on the object I pass to the `DefaultScheduleEvent`, which has the event title too.

The solution I found was to use `display:none;` for the css class `.fc-event-time` which will hide all the event times in the schedule.

So what I want to do is when I a new `DefaultScheduleEvent` is created :

```
defaultScheduleEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(item.getFormule().getLibelle(), startPlanningDate, endPlanningDate, "formuleColor" + item.getFormuleCremation().getId());
```

it will call the `item.isDispo()`, if it's true then we hide the event time, otherwise we display it.

How can I do this ?

Comment: have you tried to use rendered with item.isDispo()?

Comment: @BillyHope where can I use rendered ? in the xhtml code you only call the p:schedule element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this two ways:

1. extend `fc-time` css

**css**

```
.fc-time, .hide-time {
    display:none;
}
```

**bean**

```
String hideCss = "";

if (item.isDispo()) {
    hideCss = "hide-time";
}

defaultScheduleEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(item.getFormule().getLibelle(), startPlanningDate, endPlanningDate, "formuleColor" + item.getFormuleCremation().getId() + " " + hideCss);
```

2. set `allDay` flag to true

**bean**

```
defaultScheduleEvent = new DefaultScheduleEvent(item.getFormule().getLibelle(), startPlanningDate, endPlanningDate, item.isDispo());
```

The second way is not applicable in your case since your adding `"formuleColor" + item.getFormuleCremation().getId()` as custom css

Hope this helps.

Comment: The first solution won't work, since when you add the `hide-time` class it will hide the whole event in the schedule, and the div that should be hidden is a child of the event element.

Comment: `div` `fc-content` has two `span` as child that has `fc-time` and `fc-title` class respectively.
You can check this in your browser's Developer Tool (press F12).
My solution only adds hide-time in `fc-time`.
have you tried it? It works perfectly fine in my app though.

Comment: thanks for help, I solved it using your method, but instead of `.fc-time, .hide-time {display:none;}` I used : `.hide-time .fc-time {display:none;}`

Comment: Good to hear you solved your problem. 
Please mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful.